# Problema ao alinhar botões com imagem, em uma widget, utilizando biblioteca gráfica pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, imagem, eventos, gui, pyqt-5

Estou tentado criar uma tela com uma imagem de background e dois botões (ok e cancel) com efeito de pressionado/solto usando a biblioteca gráfica `pyqt5`,  da linguagem de programação `python`, porém, estou com dois problemas: não consigo alinhar os botões para o centro do widget e o evento dos botões parecem estar acontecendo duas vezes.

Abaixo segue o código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class PicButton(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, pixmap_pressed, id_button, parent=None):
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.pixmap_pressed = pixmap_pressed
        self.id_buton = id_button

        self.pressed.connect(self.update)
        self.released.connect(self.update)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isDown():
            pix = self.pixmap_pressed
            print("botao pressionado: ", self.id_buton)
        else:
            pix = self.pixmap

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(131, 82)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setGeometry(800, 450, 800, 450)

pixmap = QPixmap("background.png")
brush = QBrush(pixmap)
palette = QPalette()
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, brush)
window.setPalette(palette)
button1 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_down.png"), "cancel")
button2 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("ok_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("ok_down.png"), "ok")

layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addStretch(1)
layout.addWidget(button1)
layout.addWidget(button2)
layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Para obter as imagens utilizadas no programa baixe-os no seguinte link: 
[imagens](http://www.filedropper.com/imagens).

Alguém saberia me dizer como resolver esses problemas?

Answer (score 0):

Os eventos estão sendo ativados duas vezes pois há duas chamadas para os mesmos.

Para corrigir, bastar retirar as linhas

```
self.pressed.connect(self.update)
self.released.connect(self.update)
```

Sobre centralizar a imagem, basta retirar o comando

```
layout.addStretch(1)
```

Já que assim você adiciona um [QSpacerItem](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/qspaceritem.html) fazendo seus botões irem para a lateral.

No final, o código ficaria assim:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class PicButton(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, pixmap_pressed, id_button, parent=None):
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.pixmap_pressed = pixmap_pressed
        self.id_buton = id_button

        self.pressed.connect(self.update)
        self.released.connect(self.update)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isDown():
            pix = self.pixmap_pressed
            print("botao pressionado: ", self.id_buton)
        else:
            pix = self.pixmap

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(131, 82)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setGeometry(800, 450, 800, 450)

pixmap = QPixmap("background.png")
brush = QBrush(pixmap)
palette = QPalette()
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, brush)
window.setPalette(palette)
button1 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("cancel_down.png"), "cancel")
button2 = PicButton(QtGui.QPixmap("ok_up.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("ok_down.png"), "ok")


layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addStretch(0)
layout.addWidget(button1)
layout.addWidget(button2)
layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]